# Tagging AWS RDS Cluster vs Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an AWS RDS Cluster with one writer and one reader instances. I have tagged the parent cluster with relevant tags. However I do see further tagging support available on individual instances as well. So from cost calculation perspective wrt a given tag, will the tag at cluster level be sufficient or do I have to tag each and every instance under that cluster?
Also if I have enabled auto scaling support in RDS then how do I make sure that new auto scaled RDS instance gets tagged as well?

Comment: What kind of scaling support were you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same question recently. Tagging the cluster does not automatically apply to the instances for consideration of costs -- the instances also need to be tagged.